# Cakephp ajax insert without using cake ajaxhelper

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am trying to add data in cakephp by ajax without using ajax helper.Here insertion is working fine but problem is after insert data I have failed to see the success massage.Here is my effort.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
        x=$("#rform").serializeArray();
        $.post($("#rform").attr("action"),
                x,
                function(data)
                {

                    $("#success").html(data);
                    $("#success").fadeIn(); 
                    $("#success").fadeOut(2800); 
                    $("input").val('');
                });
        $("#rform").submit(function(){
            return false;
        });
});

});

</script>
```

Here is the add.ctp code

```
<?php 

    echo $this->Form->create('Info',array(
        'id' => 'rform'
        )); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Info'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php 
$options = array
(
    'label' => 'Add',
    'value' => 'Add',
    'id' => 'submit'

);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
</div>
<div style="color:green;" id="success">

</div>
```

Here after add it is repeating insertion page again in bellow.Here I need to show only success massage.If I remove `$("#success").html(data);` nothing is happening but after insert button name making disappear.How can I add success massage in here ?

Comment: Could you add some text in #submit div and check if it's visible? Without submitting the form. Just refresh.

Comment: You could also post the code from the method used on the server for processing this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by little bit change

```
 $("#success").html(data);
```

to

```
$("#success").html("Insert Success");
```

and here I have changed input button tag, I have use direct button here

```
<button id="submit">Submit </button>
```